# JQuery remove() not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to take the text in all labels and add it to the input's placeholder. I am deliberately leaving the `<strong>` text alone.

I have it working great in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE it stops before the last step of the first label. How can I make this work in IE?

JQuery:

```
$("li label").each(function() {
    var label = $(this);
    var placeholder = label.contents().get(0).nodeValue;
    label.closest("li").find("input").attr("placeholder", placeholder).val("").focus().blur();
    label.contents().get(0).remove();
  });
```

Example HTML:

```
  <li>
    <label for="field-1">My Label<strong>required</strong></label>
    <input id="field-1" type="text">
  </li>
```

Comment: what jq version are you using? should make such big difference though

Comment: @Gary jQuery v1.11.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[.get(index)](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the dom element reference of the element in the passed index, so `label.contents().get(0).remove();` calls the dom element's [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Browser_compatibility) method(Supported only on Edge)

Use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the jQuery element reference and then call the [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method

```
label.contents().eq(0).remove();
```